# How many ways are there for arranging letters of the word AMAZING?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there for arranging letters of the word $AMAZING$ such that the '$I$' appears between the two '$A$'s ?

---

Answer given is $5$!, but I doubt that.

As a word $AMINZAG$ is also allowed here .

Comment: It depends on what is meant by "between". I would say that in AMIZANG the I appears between the two A's, so the word would be allowed; with this interpretation you are right and $5!=120$ is too small a number. Indeed the answer would be $\frac{7!}{3!}=840$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the letters $AIA$ must appear tight together you have that there is $5!$ ways. The reason is that you have the problem in permuting the fragments $AIA$, $M$, $Z$, $N$, $G$ that is $5$ fragments.

If on the other hand you only require that $I$ is somewhere between the $A$s, not requiring them to be tight together. This interpretation allows for $AMINZAG$ for example. The solution is to consider all the permutations of the letters and interpreting the $A$s to be distinct. This gives $7!$ permutations, but not all are allowed. You still have to consider the relative ordering of the $A$s and $I$, these can be ordered in $3!$ ways of which only $2$ are allowed (but they are also considered equal so while we multiply with $2$ we would also have to divide by $2$). The result taking this into account becomes:

$${7!\over 3!} = 840$$

Considering the given answer is $5!$ we therefore can conclude that it's the first interpretation that is the "correct".

Comment: This is a well explained answer !!!
But I was thinking that in this question there are some repeated letters in the word. Lets say that we have a word $"DERMATOGLYPHICS"$ which is one of the longest word in the English dictionary without any repeated letters. Then what are the number of ways that "L" comes in between "M" and "C" not necessarily tightly coupled together?

Answer (score 5):

Since you want $I$ between two $A$'s, make a seperate unit of $$\underbrace{\boxed{AIA}}_{\text{Single Unit}}$$

Now what you are left with is, arranging $\boxed{AIA} , M , Z, N, G$ . You can arrange these in $5!$ ways.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question meant directly between two $A's$.If so, then

Here's a solution:

$4!$ ways of writing it like this $AIA****$

$4!$ ways of writing it like this $*AIA***$

$4!$ ways of writing it like this $**AIA**$

$4!$ ways of writing it like this $***AIA*$

$4!$ ways of writing it like this $****AIA$

Total ways =$$4!+4!+4!+4!+4!=5(4!)=5!$$