# How many ways are there for arranging letters of the word $DERMATOGLYPHICS$ such that the $‘L’$ appears between $'M'$ and $'C'$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

> How many ways are there for arranging letters of the word
> $DERMATOGLYPHICS$ such that the $'L'$ appears between $'M'$ and $'C'$
> not necessarily coupled together?

We can see that this word has no repeated letters.

 `PS : This is one of the two longest words in English dictionary that has no repeated letters.`

Total number of letters : $15$
Number of ways these letters can be arranged = $15!$
Now I know not all the arrangements will suit the requirement of the question. How can we separate them out? Please help me on this !!!

Can the answer be $\frac{15!\times2}{3!} $? I came to answer this way by following the approach mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189055/how-many-ways-are-there-for-arranging-letters-of-the-word-amazing).
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Is $...C...L...M...$ acceptable or only $...M...L...C...$?

Comment: both are acceptable...but it would be nice if you can also show for the individual cases too...that will be a learning for me too.
I added my answer. Please see that too.

Comment: Consider the sequences CLM, CML, LMC, LCM, MLC, MCL.  Consider assigning each 15 letter sequence to the appropriate one of the 6 possible ways of ordering the letters C, M, L.  So, you have 6 different groups of 15 letter sequences.  What does your **intuition** suggest about the **relative** number of sequences in each group?  Do you think that the number of sequences in each group are (perhaps) not equal to each other?

Comment: Hint: Group the set of all permutations of the words by putting the cases of with the same order of $C,L,M$ in the same group. Show each group has the same number of elements.

Comment: @All : Please provide in a detailed solution as I am not getting confused here. A solution will be really helpful.

Comment: @Ganit: People are deliberately being careful not to do your homework for you. You can expect hints that help you solve the problem yourself, but not complete written-out solutions.

Comment: yeah I know...but with the hints... I am not able to move forward... and this question is not something as part of my homework. I came across the question that I have mentioned in the description...and that made me thought what if all the words are different. that's why I asked this question and i have also put up my answer there based on what I could understand from that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Here is one way to see it. We have $15$ positions to fill with the $15$ distinct letters in the word DERMATOGLYPHICS. Select three of the $15$ positions for the C, L, and M, which can be done in $\binom{15}{3}$ ways.  The L must be placed in the middle of the three selected positions.  The C and M can be arranged in the other two selected positions in $2!$ ways.  The remaining $12$ letters can be placed in the remaining $12$ positions in $12!$ ways.  Hence, the number of arrangements of the letters of the word DERMATOGLYPHICS in which the L appears somewhere between the C and the M is
$$\binom{15}{3}2!12! = \frac{15!}{3!12!} \cdot 2!12! = \frac{15!2!}{3!} = \frac{15! \cdot 2}{3!}$$
as you found.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First, figure out: How many ways are there to place all of the letters except for $C,L$ and $M$?

Once all the other letters are placed, there are three blank spots remaining in the word, where you need to place $C,L$ and $M$ so that $L$ appears between $C$ and $M$. How many ways are there to place these three remaining letters? Does this answer depend on how the non-$CLM$ letters were placed?

Comment: one way to put L is MLC too..